# not run a spec by default unless flag is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

We have a set of controller specs to ensure that our api is working as anticipated.

I'd also like to add a performance test that is not run by default but could be run (perhaps even as simply as via the line number like `rspec spec/controllers/item_controller.rb:50`. Some of these could be a couple of seconds so we don't want to be running every time (4 seconds x 30 actions adds up).

Is there a way to exclude a spec or describe block by default but have it be run via line number?

Answer (score 4):

Add a tag to each of your slow tests to identify them, e.g.,

```
it 'should do something', slow: true do
  #does something
end
```

Then simply run rspec with the exclusive tag option:

```
rspec --tag ~slow
```

This will run all tests that don't have the `slow` tag associated with them. To run the slow tests in conjunction with your other tests simply invoke without the tag option.

It might be preferable to have this as the default behaviour, in which case modify the `.rspec` configuration file and add the following to it:

```
--tag ~slow
```

Now by default when you simply run `rspec` all tests will run except the ones tagged as being slow. To run the slow tests explicitly set the flag:

```
rspec --tag slow
```

Though this will exclude all tests that aren't tagged as being slow.

Comment: so, no way to write a spec that does not run **by default** -- ie, without any extraneous setup?

Comment: yes .. set the tag on the tests you don't want to run by default and add that tag to be excluded to your .rspec configuration file ... I have covered this in the answer.

Comment: @David Thank you very very much, your answer was perfect.  Worked like a charm.  Unfortunate that the other guy didn't really understand what you were saying and was so rude about it.  I wish I could accept your answer on his behalf.